# Syncing a directory with an SVN repository

Tags: svn, version-control

I need to create/update/delete files in a directory (and its subdirectories) every time an SVN repo is updated.

I was told this can be done writing a script which uses output from `svnlook changed` command.

I wonder: Is there an already written script for this?

<s>**Added:** I think `svnsync` is not suitable for this, as it needs the synced repository to have .svn folders what is no good for us.</s> (it was even more wrong: `svnsync` synchronized repos not working dirs, which I need to synchronize)

Comment: How soon after the repo is updated do you need the directory synced?

Answer (score 0):

`svnlook` is usually used in a post-commit hook, but the hooks are run by SVN server.  So unless your directory is located on the SVN server, it won't do you much good.

Consider creating a simple cron job with `svn update`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an already written script for this?

Yes.

I know (and wrote here, at SO, URLs) about at least two bash-scripts (sync single revision or revisions-range) and one in Ruby, suitable for using in post-commit hook (where DEST DIR is local in all cases)